# Best way to roll back actions when an exception is raised with Python

Tags: python, exception, rollback, undo, ctrl

I have a code who looks like this :

```
# step 1 remove from switch    
for server in server_list:
    remove_server_from_switch(server)
    logger.info("OK : Removed %s", server)

# step 2 remove port
for port in port_list:
    remove_ports_from_switch(port)
    logger.info("OK : Removed port %s", port)

# step 3 execute the other operations
for descr in pairs:
    move_descr(descr)

# step 4 add server back to switch    
for server in server_list:
    add_server_to_switch(server)
    logger.info("OK : server added %s", server)

# step 5 add back port 
for port in port_list:
    add_ports_to_switch(port)
    logger.info("OK : Added port %s", port)
```

functions inside the for loop can raise exceptions or the user can interrupt the script with the Ctrl+C.
But I would like to enter in a roll-back mode by undo changes already done before if exceptions are raised during the execution.
I mean, if an exception is raised during the step 3, I have to roll-back steps 1 and 2 (by executing actions in step 4 and 5 ).
Or if a user try to stop the script with a Ctrl+C in the middle of for loop in the step 1, I would like to roll-back the action and add back the servers removed.

How can it be done in a good pythonic way with the use of exceptions, please ? :)

Answer (score 3):

This is what context managers are for. Read up on the [with statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) for details, but the general idea is you need to write context manager classes where the `__enter__` and `__exit__` functions do the removal/re-addition of your servers/ports. Then your code structure becomes something like:

```
with RemoveServers(server_list):
    with RemovePorts(port_list):
        do_stuff
# exiting the with blocks will undo the actions
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a [with](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) construct.

As [this link](https://realpython.com/python-with-statement/#the-with-statement-approach) explains:

```
with expression as target_var:
    do_something(target_var)
```

> The context manager object results from evaluating the expression
> after with. In other words, expression must return an object that
> implements the context management protocol. This protocol consists of
> two special methods:

```
.__enter__() is called by the with statement to enter the runtime context.
.__exit__() is called when the execution leaves the with code block.
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this will work:

```
undo_dict = {remove_server_from_switch: add_server_to_switch,
             remove_ports_from_switch: add_ports_to_switch,
             add_server_to_switch: remove_server_from_switch,
             add_ports_to_switch: remove_ports_from_switch}

def undo_action(action):
    args = action[1:]
    func = action[0]
    undo_dict[func](*args)

try:

    #keep track of all successfully executed actions
    action_list = []

    # step 1 remove from switch    
    for server in server_list:
        remove_server_from_switch(server)
        logger.info("OK : Removed %s", server)
        action_list.append((remove_server_from_switch, server))

    # step 2 remove port
    for port in port_list:
        remove_ports_from_switch(port)
        logger.info("OK : Removed port %s", port)
        action_list.append((remove_ports_from_switch, port))

    # step 3 execute the other operations
    for descr in pairs:
        move_descr(descr)

    # step 4 add server back to switch    
    for server in server_list:
        add_server_to_switch(server)
        logger.info("OK : server added %s", server)
        action_list.append((add_server_to_switch, server))

    # step 5 add back port 
    for port in port_list:
        add_ports_to_switch(port)
        logger.info("OK : Added port %s", port)
        action_list.append((add_ports_to_switch, port))

except Exception:
    for action in reverse(action_list):
        undo_action(action)
        logger.info("ERROR Recovery : undoing {func}({args})",func = action[0], args = action[1:])

finally:
    del action_list
```

EDIT: [As tzaman said below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28031889/2437514), the best  thing to do in a situation like this is to wrap the entire thing into a context manager, and use the `with` statement. Then it doesn't matter whether or not there was an error encountered- all your actions are undone at the end of the `with` block.

Here's what it might look like:

```
class ActionManager():
    def __init__(self, undo_dict):
        self.action_list = []
        self.undo_dict = undo_dict
    def action_pop(self):
        yield self.action_list.pop()
    def action_add(self, *args):
        self.action_list.append(args)
    def undo_action(self, action):
        args = action[1:]
        func = action[0]
        self.undo_dict[func](*args)
    def __enter__(self):
        return self
    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        for action in self.action_stack:
            undo_action(action)
            logger.info("Action Manager Cleanup : undoing {func}({args})",func = action[0], args = action[1:])
```

Now you can just do this:

```
#same undo_dict as before
with ActionManager(undo_dict) as am:

    # step 1 remove from switch    
    for server in server_list:
        remove_server_from_switch(server)
        logger.info("OK : Removed %s", server)
        am.action_add(remove_server_from_switch, server)

    # step 2 remove port
    for port in port_list:
        remove_ports_from_switch(port)
        logger.info("OK : Removed port %s", port)
        am.action_add(remove_ports_from_switch, port)

    # step 3 execute the other operations
    for descr in pairs:
        move_descr(descr)

    # steps 4 and 5 occur automatically
```

Another way to do it - and probably a lot better - would be to add the servers/ports in the `__enter__` method. You could subclass the `ActionManager` above and add the port addition and removal logic inside of it.

The `__enter__` method doesn't even have to return an instance of the `ActionManager` class - if it makes sense to do so, you could even write it so that `with SwitchManager(servers,ports)` returns your pairs object, and you could end up doing this:

```
with SwitchManager(servers, ports) as pairs:
    for descr in pairs:
        move_descr(descr)
```